# Ayuda con formula para PBI

Tags: powerbi

compañeros tengo que realizar un conteo por codigos de clasificacion de facturas, tengo los siguientes escenarios, 
para las facturas que tengan los codigos de clasificacion (010,013,035,038,048,047) necesito que haga un DISTINCTCOUNT y para los demas facturas con cod_clasif diferente me haga un COUNT, para asi conocer la cantidad de facturas que son con conteo distintivo y cuantas con conteo normal. esto se da ya que los codigos de clasificacion (010,013,035,038,048,047) aun que la factura se repita se necesita solo contar una vez el mismo registro. 
tengo una idea de la formula pero no la pego en sintaxis.

```
if cod_clasif = (DISTINCTCOUNT(010,013,035,038,048,047) ELSE COUNT(IVD[NO_FISICO])
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto te funcionará:

```
NumeroDeCodigos = IF(MAX(Codigos[Codigo]) IN {"010","013","035","038","048","047"};DISTINCTCOUNT(IVD[NO_FISICO]);COUNT(IVD[NO_FISICO]))
```

Teniendo en cuenta que `Codigos[Codigo]` es la tabla y campo donde tienes los códigos de clasificación, `IVD` es la tabla de facturas y `[NO_FISICO]` es el campo donde almacenas el código de clasificación cada factura.

Dependiendo de tu modelo de datos, los campos y tablas pueden variar. Pero aqui puedes ver como hacer el `IF`

Comment: Buena tarde Don Roger, resulta que aplique su formula pero no me hace el conteo distintivo para los codigos dentro del IN..

Comment: Asegúrate que donde la fórmula pone `Codigos[Codigo]` tu lo cambias por la tabla y campo que contiene los códigos.